# macOS-like look and behavior on Linux

Tags: window, frames

I would like to get macOS-like look and behavior on Linux, e.g. global(app) menu, no border on the top of Emacs window etc. I don't care about fancy icons and themes, but these two features are key for me.
On which distro / desktop environment it is the easiest to achive? Which packages or plugins do I have to install or others changes in config files.

Comment: Please be more specific. SE is for specific Q & A. E.g., ask about just how to get a frame with some (specific) characteristics. Otherwise the question is too broad and risks being closed. And please narrow the question to just Emacs, not making macOS itself look like GNU/Linux, but making some bit of Emacs look that way on macOS. Thx.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I mean more modern look of Emacs. E.g. only title bar with buttons in the main window, menu bar on the bar top of the screen. I found some plugins on XFCE and KDE desktops, but don't work properly with Emacs.

Comment: This is overly broad, as you're crossing the application and desktop environment (DE) boundary. As someone who's done something similar several times, I'd recommend starting out with addressing your DE, and then getting more specific with applications. For Linux in 2019, take a look at [elementaryOS](https://elementary.io/) or [Solus](https://getsol.us/home/). Solus's default desktop, [Budgie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budgie_(desktop_environment)) is available elsewhere, like [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/). That will address some of your questions. For others, come back here.